# Java File.isDirectory() returns False for a Directory in Linux

Tags: java, file-io

Please see code snippet:

```
File[] additionalFiles = new File(FILE_PATH).listFiles();
boolean isDirectory = file.isDirectory();
```

I have verified that the directory path is correct, and when I run the code on Windows, the value of isDirectory is true (as it should be).  Any suggestions as to why this occurs on Linux (RedHat Enterprise Linux)?

Comment: Is the directory a regular directory, or a symlink? What version of Java? What version of RH? Does the directory contain any unusual (non-English) characters in the name?

Comment: What is the value of `FILE_PATH`? Does it by any chance contain Windows-style file separators ('\')?

Comment: I believe it is a simlink, the directory is out on a shared server- how does that impact?  The Java version is 6 update 17.  The RH version is Enterprise RedHat 5.  The directory contains all lower case letters, no special characters, and the file separators are correct (I printed out the directory when running the program, then copied and pasted it in the command line after "cd" and successfully and cd'd to the directory).

Answer (score 8):

Symlinks don't read as directories, if I remember correctly. The right way around that is:

```
 new File(FILE_PATH).getCanonicalFile().isDirectory();
```

(NOTE: Untested, I don't have a linux box to test this on easily).

Answer (score 6):

I experienced this issue once. My case is so funny, I was reading the path from a properties file and that path contained a tab character at the end of the string. That was the reason why the path wasn't recognized as a directory

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this link
https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug;jsessionid=56e03cb783aaf9725daf5ec8d8?bug_id=6539692

You may have this issue.

Otherwise I would guess an issue with file permissions (though that might throw back security exception and I am assuming your code does not wrap it and return false) or may be a sym link issue that I dont know much about.